# XML: Return elements of a sequence that satisfy given condition

Tags: xml, xquery

I have an XML file with information on movies. I want my expression to return the directors in the XML that have directed more than 1 movie.

What I have now is:

```
for $director in //director
where count($director) > 1
return $director
```

This does not produce anything. What I'm trying to do is:

For every director in the XML:
return director's name IF the director's name is named more than once in //director

How would you solve this problem?

EDIT: Sample of the XML:

```
<result>
    <videos>
        <video id="id1235AA0">
            <title>The Fugitive</title>
            <genre>action</genre>
            <rating>PG-13</rating>
            <summary>Tommy Lee Jones and Harrison Ford are the hunter and the hunted in this fast-paced story of a falsely convicted man who escapes to find his wife's true killer.</summary>
            <details>Harrison Ford and Tommy Lee Jones race through the breathless manhunt movie based on the classic TV series. Ford is prison escapee Dr. Richard Kimble, a Chicago surgeon falsely convicted of killing his wife and determined to prove his innocence by leading his pursuers to the one-armed man who actually commited the crime.</details>
            <year>1997</year>
            <director>Andrew Davis</director>
            <studio>Warner</studio>
            <user_rating>4</user_rating>
            <runtime>110</runtime>
            <actorRef>00000003</actorRef>
            <actorRef>00000006</actorRef>
            <vhs>13.99</vhs>
            <vhs_stock>206</vhs_stock>
            <dvd>14.99</dvd>
            <dvd_stock>125</dvd_stock>
            <beta>1.03</beta>
            <beta_stock>12</beta_stock>
            <LaserDisk>12.00</LaserDisk>
            <LaserDisk_stock>10</LaserDisk_stock>
        </video>
    </videos>
</result>
```

Comment: If you want to list directors having more than one movie, make sure to provide an example that actually works for your question: I'd propose to have at least three movies, two with the same director and one with another, so there are both directors that match and such ones that don't. At the same time, you could omit most of the other, irrelevant tags.

Comment: And don't post the [exactly same question multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32924082/xml-return-elements-of-a-sequence-that-occur-certain-number-of-times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not performing an aggregation at all. If your XQuery engine supports XQuery 3.0, use `group by`:

```
for $director in //director
where count($director) > 1
group by $director
return $director
```

Otherwise, loop over all `distinct-values(//director)`, find all matching director tags for each of the names and count them.